# antlr4 json grammar and indirect left recursion

Tags: antlr4

I read "The Definite ANTLR4 Reference" and it says

> While ANTLR v4 can handle direct left recursion, it can’t handle indirect left
>   recursion.

on page 71.
But in json grammar on page 90 i see next

```
grammar JSON;

json:   object
    |   array
    ;

object
    :   '{' pair (',' pair)* '}'
    |   '{' '}' // empty object
    ;
pair:   STRING ':' value ;

array
    :   '[' value (',' value)* ']'
    |   '[' ']' // empty array
    ;

value
    :   STRING
    |   NUMBER
    |   object  // indirect recursion
    |   array   // indirec recursion
    |   'true'
    |   'false'
    |   'null'
    ;
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Describe the difference in the reference and the grammar to make your _is it correct?_ easier to understand and answer.

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer was not clear. The book says that antlr can't recognize indirect left recursion, but at the same time it use indirect left recursion (rule "value" above). My question is: how can this be? Maybe I don't understand something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON grammar you mentioned is not a problem because it actually doesn't contain any indirect left recursion.

The rule `value` can produce `array` and `array` can again produce something which contains `value`, but not as it's leftmost part. (there is a `[` preceding `value`)

The `value` rule would only be a problem if there would be some way to produce `value` folowed by any terminals and non-terminals.

From the book

> A left-recursive rule is one that
>   either directly or indirectly invokes itself on the left edge of an alternative.

Example:

```
expr : expr '*' expr // match subexpressions joined with '*' 
     | expr '+' expr // match subexpressions joined with '+' operator
     | INT // matches simple integer atom
     ;
```

It is left recursion because there is at least one alternative immediatly started with `expr`. Also it is direct left recursion.

Example of indirect left recursion:

```
expr : addition // indirectly invokes expr left recursively via addition
     | ...
     ;

addition : expr '+' expr 
         ;
```